# Graphical transformation : reflect and shift

Tags: functions, transformation, convolution

I know that x[-n] will be reflection of x[n] along y-axis and x[n+k] will shift x[n] to left by k points.
Now if I take x[n]
1. x'[n]=x[-n]  should reflect along y axis
2. x'[n+k]=x[k-n] should shilf x[-n] left by k points.
 but instead of this its actually shifted to right by k points.

can you explain me this.
Thank you

Comment: You need to explain your notations. What are all these $x[n]$?

Comment: you can assume x[n] any function either continuous or discrete  say x[n]=unit step

Comment: How does $x'[n+k]=x[k-n]$? What does the $'$ do?